# How do I delete a merge from github, permanently?

Tags: git, github

I accidently merged a project with another project that had nothing to do with it, which I didn't want to do. I successfully unmerged the projects. However, now I want to delete the erroneous commits. How do I do this.

I tried using git rebase, but it doesn't display the merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already successfully unmerged the projects (which I assume you did through a git reset --hard HEAD~N), then you need to force the changes onto the "mainline" via a:

```
git push -f
```

Please note that this isn't generally advised unless you know for sure that no one pulled from the "mainline" after you accidentally made an undesired commit.

Comment: Inadvisable if it's a repository that anyone has forked and made changes since the bad commit. If you do it fast enough it's usually not a problem.

Comment: @Abizern: I completely agree but as you said, it's usually not a problem.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Why doesn't aren't the merges available under rebase? Is this part of the Git design?

Comment: @gersh: I'm not sure I understand your question.